# Different version of Java in cygwin

Tags: java, cygwin

Today I installed cygwin and I was checking my JAVA HOME and other settings and I found out very strange thing..

When I do, `echo $JAVA_HOME`, I always get `C:\Java\jdk1.6.0_26` which is fine and that's what I have already set to `jdk1.6.0_26` in my environment variables as well but when I do java -version, I always get different version of java, I always see 1.7..

```
uname@D-PHC-22334455 /cygdrive/c
$ echo $JAVA_HOME
C:\Java\jdk1.6.0_26

uname@D-PHC-22334455 /cygdrive/c
$ which java
/cygdrive/c/WINDOWS/system32/java

uname@D-PHC-22334455 /cygdrive/c
$ java -version
java version "1.7.0_25"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_25-b17)
Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (build 23.25-b01, mixed mode)
```

I have already checked my PATH variables and JAVA_HOME as well.. Both are pointing to jdk1.6
Can anybody explain what wrong has happened?

Below is my PATH variable-

```
uname@D-PHC-22334455 /cygdrive/c
$ echo $PATH
/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/cygdrive/c/Java/jdk1.6.0_26:/cygdrive/c/Program Files (x86)/DataStax Community/python:/cygdrive/c/Users/uname/openssl/bin:/cygdrive/c/Python27:/cygdrive/c/Python27/Scripts:/cygdrive/d/app/uname/product/11.1.0/db_1/bin:/cygdrive/c/apache-maven-3.0.4-bin/apache-maven-3.0.4/bin:/cygdrive/c/Program Files (x86)/IBM/RationalSDLC/Clearquest/cqcli/bin:/cygdrive/c/Perl64/bin:/cygdrive/c/WINDOWS/system32:/cygdrive/c/WINDOWS:/cygdrive/c/WINDOWS/System32/Wbem:/cygdrive/c/WINDOWS/System32/WindowsPowerShell/v1.0:/cygdrive/c/Perl64/bin:/cygdrive/c/Program Files (x86)/Perforce:/cygdrive/c/Program Files (x86)/IBM/RationalSDLC/ClearCase/bin:/cygdrive/c/Program Files (x86)/IBM/RationalSDLC/common:/cygdrive/d/ede-5.1.1/apache-ant-1.7.1.2008.06.27/bin:/cygdrive/c/Program Files (x86)/Git/cmd:/usr/bin:/cygdrive/c/Program Files/Common Files/Hitachi ID:/cygdrive/c/Eclipse-C++/MinGW:/etc/alternatives:%APPDATA%/Python/Scripts
```

Answer (score 2):

So the Java installed must be `Java 1.7.0_25` as it says in

```
uname@D-PHC-22334455 /cygdrive/c
$ which java
/cygdrive/c/WINDOWS/system32/java
```

even though your `PATH` points to `C:\Java\jdk1.6.0_26`.

`/Windows/system32` is always searched first.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion but how to fix this thing? I want to use jdk1.6 consistent everywhere.. Any thoughts?

Comment: @TrekkieTechieT-T Replace the `java.exe` program in `system32` with the one in your 1.6 installation's bin folder.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try to rename the java file `/cygdrive/c/WINDOWS/system32/java` to `/cygdrive/c/WINDOWS/system32/java.back` then  add again (if it still doesn't work) the java path to the paths:
 `export JAVA_HOME="/cygdrive/c/Java/jdk1.6.0_26"` 
 `export PATH="$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin"`